# How to copy files and keep the structure?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, file-transfer

I have a text file with a list of filenames

```
c:\superawesome\lame.mp3
c:\noyoucant\wujuu.mp3
d:\bottle\water.obj
```

And I want to copy the same file structure in a different location (`e:\backup`). The resulting structure would look like this

```
e:\backup\superawesome\lame.mp3
e:\backup\noyoucant\wujuu.mp3
e:\backup\bottle\water.obj
```

Backup is an empty folder. I've tried using `copy c:\superawesome\lame.mp3 e:\backup\superawesome\lame.mp3` and the same using `xcopy`

How can I copy the list of files and keep the original folder structure?

Comment: Rather than a batch file, you can use many backup/mirror tools out there. Many of them are free and they also offer nice features such as file type matching, file name matching and many more.

Comment: @tumchaaditya In my particular case, a bach is ideal. It's a one-tiime task.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    set "target=e:\backup"

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("TextFile.txt") do (
        md "%target%%%~pa" 2>nul
        copy /y "%%a" "%target%%%~pa"
    )
```

For each line (file) inside the list, create, under the target folder, the same path indicated in the readed line (`%%~pa` is the path of the element referenced by `%%a`). Then, copy the readed file to the target folder

Comment: I have a list of paths/files in quotes and was only getting the folder structure. Figured out that, after removing the quotes, it works! Thanks! (Windows 10 Ent.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (TextFile.txt) do call :BeginCopy "%%a"
goto :end

:BeginCopy

set SrcFolder=%~1
set DestFolder=%SrcFolder:~7,-1%
echo %DestFolder%
xcopy /s /e /i /h /r /y %SrcFolder%  "e:\backup\%DestFolder%" 

goto :end
```

For further reading visit: [Xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: WoW! Very Impressive! So much flags!

Comment: what if the input text filename has spaces?

Comment: It works but xcopy ask to create file or directory. Also, filenames are incomplete. Strange...