# How do I move a series of files to a parallel folder structure in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ms-dos

I've a folder that has both image and video folders which I want to separate into separate folders based on the file type.   I want this to be a script so that i can re run it when more files are imported

**Current file structure**

Currently images and videos are in a folder where they are combined by date

```
Images/
    2018-08/
          image1.png
          Video1.mp4
    2018-09/
          image1.png
          video1.mp4
```

**Target Structure**

After running the script I would like the folder structure and file names been retained with the point of having the images remain in the images structure and the videos being moved into a separate structure.

```
Images/
    2018-08/
          image1.png
    2018-09/
          image1.png
Videos/
    2018-08/
          Video1.mp4
    2018-09/
          video1.mp4
```

**What i've tried so far**

I've looked at the windows [move](https://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) command but it seems only to apply to a single folder.

Also I looked at then solution to [How to copy files and keep the structure?](https://superuser.com/questions/816840/how-to-copy-files-and-keep-the-structure).  It almost solves my problem except I don't have a predefined list of files just pre defined extension and starting folder.

**Some notes**

- The Higher folders e.g. Images and Videos will be predefined and are static
- The sub-folders below images need to be automatically replicated
- File names may duplicate between moves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `robocopy` which is built in to Windows 7 and above.

It can move files and folders with a specific mask.

In your case, it should work using something like this:
`robocopy \images \videos *.mp4 /copyall /s /mov`

I would recommend testing this on a few folders and files before running it on a large folder structure that could be really jumbled around, until you get the command just right.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: I tried /copyall and had an issue with the Auditing information permissions so tried /copy:DAT are there any concerns when not including S NTFS access control list (ACL), O Owner information, U Auditing information?

Comment: @user1605665 not really. Now that you mention it I seem to remember similar issues myself. This would be more important in a business network with different users on a server / computer. If they are just your files on your computer, it really doesn’t matter. The files inherit permissions from the parent folder anyways.